# Spring Boot Integration test with H2 inmemory database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, h2

I tried various approach but I am confused now, I have spring boot application for which I'm writing integration test with inmemory h2 database.

this is application.yml

```
spring.profiles: test
spring.datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
    # enable H2 web console and set url for web console
      # http://localhost:8080/console
    h2:
      console:
        enabled: true
        path: /console
    schema: schema.sql
    data: data.sql
```

and I start the console by starting the server from here to test it in debug mode of test

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() throws SQLException {
    Server webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8081");
    webServer.start();
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
    registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
    return registration;
}
```

I'm able to view the console on 8081 port but I am not able to see the schema which I popultaed from yml file. Please help.

Comment: try using mode for example: MODE=MYSQL in your url

Comment: Can you see the sql being loaded into the DB?

Comment: @GurinderSPanesar tried no luck

Comment: @AdamSmith i am trying to look into this via console, i cant see from there, how to check this?

Comment: I have a doubt, Am i doing it right way? i am starting the server ans also have a configuration in yml? if this creates two different inmemory database?

Comment: Personally I have all my DB config in a tool like liquibase, and then have liquibase load it into the H2 database.  See here: http://jannatconsulting.com/blog/?p=28

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is not working but i got his working by creating a bean for datasource through java code and loaded the script from there.